# Lookup values from table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup, xlookup

Please I want to write a formula to get the Distance (4th column) between From and To Cities  (2nd and 3rd columns) for a particular Order ID (1st column) in Table 1 while looking up data from the Distances worksheet as shown below.

[image: Table 1]

Distances worksheet:
[image: Distances worksheet]

Comment: Try index() with match() and you need a match for the column and another for the row.

Comment: since you tagged `XLOOKUP()` I'd suggest using `FILTER()` for the return-parameter. Please include your own attempt at solving your issue for debugging-purposes.

Comment: If you don't have the newest version of Excel, then just use `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: What you need is Pivot Tables. Take From and To fields into rows and columns section and distance into values section. Then OrderID could go intol filter section so you can get only the cities for a specific OrderId

Comment: @JvdV Sir, right not just `XLOOKUP()` or `FILTER()` it can be solved with `SUMPRODUCT()` & `VLOOKUP()` + `MATCH()` Function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a quick version:

```
INDEX(A2:D5,MATCH(B8,A2:A5,0),MATCH(B9,A2:D2,0))
```

[image]

B8 is the starting point, B9 end.
Did not repeat all your data as you gave it as a picture and I am too lazy to type all of that.

Answer (score 3):

### Using XLOOKUP() Function

Formula used in cell **D2** --> `Applicable To Excel 2021 & O365 Users Only`

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,$F$3:$F$7,XLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$K$2,$G$3:$K$7),"Not Found")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

So, the second `XLOOKUP()` Function returns

```
XLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$K$2,$G$3:$K$7)
```

Returns the **Distance (km)** that takes from any of the places listed in Column `B` to reach **Canberra**, since I have taken the first cell as an example so its showing for the **Canberra**, this goes same for the other **Destinations** in Column `C`

```
{285;676;1199;3735;0}
```

Lastly wrapping this one within another `XLOOKUP()` Function where the lookup value is from the Column `B` shall return the exact distance required.

## 3 Alternative formulas:

**• For All Users**

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$F$3:$K$7,MATCH(C2,$F$2:$K$2,0),0)
```

**• For Office 365 & Excel 2021**

```
=FILTER(FILTER($G$3:$K$7,(B2=$F$3:$F$7)),C2=$G$2:$K$2)
```

**• For Office 365 & Excel 2021**

```
=INDEX(FILTER($G$3:$K$7,B2=$F$3:$F$7),XMATCH(C2,$G$2:$K$2,0))
```

Note: For convenience I have shown both the tables in same worksheet, hence you may need to change the ranges accordingly as per your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with AVERAGEIFS:

[image]

Formula in cell H4:

```
=IF(H$3=$G4;"";AVERAGEIFS($D$2:$D$19;$B$2:$B$19;$G4;$C$2:$C$19;H$3))
```

Drag to left and drag to bottom.

You need to use AVERAGEIFS because distance between points is the same in both directions. Because in your data yo got, as example, `Melbourner - Sidney` in OrderId 2 and got `Sidney - Melbourne` in OrderId 4. It's the same distance duplicated so if you just sum, you will create an error.