# Excel - how to dynamically lookup a value in a table without knowing precisely what row to search

Tags: excel

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73064.png)

I'm pretty sure what I'm wanting to accomplish requires some mixture of INDEX and MATCH, possibly VLOOKUP, but I cannot figure it out.

This is an image of a mock schedule for my job, I'm wanting to create a lookup where you use the dropdown menus (in the top right) to select the time period and person whose schedule you're looking for. The ideal function combination would:

1. Find the row that corresponds to the time period.
2. Find the column that corresponds to the person within that time period (this is where I'm having trouble currently).
3. Return the specific schedule values listed above the array.

My goal is merely to make mine and my fellow coworker's lives easier when trying to sift through our very aesthetically displeasing schedule. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Index() with matches for row and column, check on here it has been done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lookup values from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71617444/lookup-values-from-table)

Comment: I don't believe either of those answer my question, because the range that it needs to search, for the person whose schedule we're looking for, changes depending which week I am searching. This is where I'm having trouble, I don't know how to tell it WHERE to search, when the WHERE is highly dependent upon which time period is chosen.

Comment: Then consider multiple levels of match(). I don't have time to try at the moment.

Comment: I ended up finding the answer, FILTER() is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I found that the FILTER function returns an array, and with some reverse engineering was able to create a set of functions that did exactly what I needed.

The function combination I needed was:

```
INDEX(array, MATCH(value, array, 0), MATCH(value, FILTER(array, array=value), 0))
```