# how to get names of matching value in excel from ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match value from different sheet to another sheet to get match value as per ID but when ever writing formula it does not give correct results

So Sheet 1

```
Name ID 
Test  1
Test2 2
```

And Sheet 2

```
ID Name
2
1
```

2
so like to match ID column from sheet 1 and populate name in Sheet2

I tried using vlookup but not working not sure is it the right way to write as am new to excel

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,Sheet2!$B$5:$C$104,2,0)
```

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` does not work right-to-left, only left-to-right. Try `XLOOKUP()`, a combination of `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`, `FILTER()`, or one of many other options.

Comment: index() with match() even works when the data is separated, but you could consider the "dirty" trick of swapping the columns... But then other functions may fail...

Comment: This has a couple of examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71617444/4961700

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered a similar problem before but i do not remember the solution. You can take the help of these subreddit as it is a similar problem.

Link- https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/jvyovz/comment/gcmz4mq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

If this is the correct solution, happy to help.